# Material-UI Autocomplete rendered values

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a ReactJs app that use a Material-UI Autocomplete component with multiple values and checkboxes totally like their code snippet :

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
```

After checking a values, that value will be rendered in a chip with a "X" button like this:
[image]

How can I change the `props` so the rendered values will be shown like "`Value A, Value B, "Value C`" with comma between them and no other styling?

Thank you for your time

Comment: can you please share your code on any platform like (jsfiddle or codepen etc.) so that one can have a look at it and debug it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

provide autocomplete `RenderTags` prop:

> Signature:
>
> function(value: T[], getTagProps: function) => ReactNode  
> value: The value provided to the component. 
> getTagProps: A tag props getter.

in your case:

```
renderTags={(values) => 
  values
  .map(value => value.title)
  .join(', ')
}
```